# How to add or remove a className when screen size change in react

Tags: reactjs

I want the className should be added or removed automatically when the screen size changes.

I tried using media queries, but that didn't really work for me. In my stylesheet I have predefined classes for example:

`.bold { font-weight: bold;}`

and this classes cannot be added or removed using media queries.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Have you considered using media queries? Please [edit] your question to add more detail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attach a resize event handler to window, then you can check the screen size and use that to update state. Then in `render`, you should check state to tell whether or not the new class should be added or removed:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.setState({
            isMobile: window.innerWidth < 1200
        });
    }, false);
}

render() {
    const className = this.state.isMobile ? 'mobile' : '';
    return (
        <Component className={className} />
    )
}
```

Comment: as an addition, if the component could potentially unmount you should also add a `componentWillUnmount` function to remove the listener otherwise it will keep erroring

Comment: I would recommend throttling the resize handler

Comment: This will be run while resizing your screen - what about to have this function to be run always not when resizing.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking to do this with hooks instead of classes, here is a simple example for this case:

```js
const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(window.innerWidth < 1200);

{/* Performs similarly to componentDidMount in classes */}
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        const ismobile = window.innerWidth < 1200;
        if (ismobile !== isMobile) setIsMobile(ismobile);
    }, false);
}, [isMobile]);

{/* There is no need for a render function with Hooks */}
return (
    <p className={`${isMobile ? "mobile-class" : "non-mobile-class"}`}>Your text here</p>
);
```

For a more in-depth explanation of the useEffect hook, check out the official React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Please note that you must be using React 16.8 or higher to take advantage of hooks.

Comment: Hi you can add a return statement in the useEffect to clean up, when it unmounts

Comment: @FaizHameed can you explain what you mean? I'm still rather new to React and I'd love to learn how to improve the code

Comment: Does this creates performance issues?

Comment: @AyushKumar it shouldn't, React hooks are designed to be efficient if used properly

Comment: @AaronMeese I am talking about memory leaks when you don't remove them, when the component unmounts.

Comment: @AyushKumar that isn't an issue as far as I am aware, but you can read more into the effects documentation related to unmounting [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) to see if it answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

the solution above is firing the event every time you resize, perhaps something like this would be a better option:

```
  const mediaQuery: string = "(min-width: 768px)";
  const mediaQueryMatch = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClassByMediaQuery = (event: { matches: any }) => {
      const isMobile = event.matches;

      return setIsMobile(isMobile);
    };
    mediaQueryMatch.addEventListener("change", handleClassByMediaQuery);

    return () => {
      mediaQueryMatch.removeEventListener("change", handleClassByMediaQuery);
    };
  }, [isMobile, mediaQueryMatch]);
```

Comment: `the solution above` Which one? The other answers are not always "above". Sure, they are while you type your answer - but then they're sorted in the page once posted. Criteria are "Trending", "Highest score", "Date modified", "Date created". Your answer is placed in the page according to this parameter.